# $200n$ diagonals are drawn in a convex $n$-gon. Prove that one of them intersects at least $10000$ others.

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, algorithms, combinatorial-geometry, discrete-optimization

> $200n$ diagonals are drawn in a convex $n$-gon. Prove that one of them intersects at least $10000$ others.

*There was no information about $n$ in a original problem.*

**Attempt:** Choose at random and uniform a diagonal with a probability $p={1\over 200n}$ and let $X$ be a number of diagonals that choosen one intersect. Then $X=X_1+X_2+...+X_{200n}$ where $X_i$ is an indicator for $i$-th diagonal to cut choosen diagonal. So $$E(X) =  E(X_1) +E(X_2)+...=   P(X_1 = 1)+...$$

I don't know how to calculate/estimate $P(X_i=1)$.

Any (**non**)probabilistic solution?

Comment: No, in fact, you can't use probability here, since you have to consider worst case.

Comment: Ok then, any other aproach...

Comment: Are there any duplicate diagonals? Or does this $n$-gon have at least $401$ sides.

Comment: Don't know, the statement was as it is with no restriction on $n$.

Comment: Consider that diagonal splits $n$-gon into two parts (say A and B) and to draw diagonals that connect vertices from part A with vertices from part B you should cross the diagonal under consideration.

Comment: Because if you can have duplicate diagonals, this is false.

Comment: What are those duplicate diagonals? @DonThousand

Comment: Note that for $n=403$, $200n$ diagonals means exactly all diagonals. So a diagonal conecting to almost opposing corners will intersect $200*201$ other diagonals.

Comment: Let's assume $n$ is large to make it interesting. I would consider a cyclic orientation, then without loss of generality, vertex $1$ see's many diagonals using pidgeonholeing. Then consider the implications of splitting the vertex set and maybe a catalan type induction (but note that wouldn't work based on the assumption $n$ is large). Kind of where my head is going as potential approach

Comment: By "splitting the vertex set" I mean if 10,000 diagonals run close to the middle, then we cannot have a diagonal between any vertices on opposite sides of these guys.

Comment: Source of this problem, please? Also, some convex $n$ gons need not have $200n$ distinct diagonals, so are you considering only those which have at least those many diagonals?

Comment: @астонвіллаолофмэллбэрг St.Petersburg 2004

Comment: Another question : if two diagonals originate from the same point, does this  count as an intersection? See, if this information is not there in the question, then we should stop pursuit : an unclear question is not worth pursuing. Just like the duplicate diagonals issue, we cannot spend time figuring the question itself  out. Also, if you've got it from a PDF or a book or something, produce that copy, there may be material preceding the question that may be useful e.g. (If you know this is not the case, inform me).

Comment: @астонвіллаолофмэллбэрг Two diagonals originating from the same point do not constitute an intersection.

Comment: @AngelaRichardson thank you , in that case I should be able to attempt the question

Answer (score 2):

In case anyone is still interested in the question, here is an approach that does not use probability.

Let $A$ denote the set of diagonals. Take a potential ``minimal counterexample" with the smallest $n$. We need to argue a contradiction. Define the **length** of a diagonal as the number of  edges on the minor arc between the two vertices.

The idea is to consider a particular diagonal. We take a parameter $\ell_0$, and consider the shortest diagonal $D$ in $A$ with length at least $\ell_0$. Suppose $D$ has length $\ell \geq \ell_0$. Then

1. This arc divides the polygon into two smaller polygons, with $\ell + 1$ and $n - \ell + 1$ vertices respectively.
2. By the minimal length condition, each member of $A$ that is a diagonal in the polygon with $\ell + 1$ edge must have length at most $\ell_0$. Thus, there are at most
   $$(\ell - 1) + \cdots + (\ell - \ell_0 + 1) = (\ell_0 - 1)(2\ell - \ell_0+2) / 2$$
   such diagonals.
3. By the minimal counterexample condition, less than $200(n - \ell + 1)$ diagonals of $A$ can be a diagonal in the the polygon with $n - \ell + 1$ edges.
4. All the other diagonals in $A$ intersect $D$.

Thus, the number of diagonals intersecting $D$ is at least
$$200n - 1 - (200(n - \ell + 1) - 1) - (\ell_0 - 1)(2\ell - \ell_0+2) / 2 = 200(\ell - 1) - (\ell_0 - 1)(2\ell - \ell_0+2) / 2$$
We can optimize over $\ell$. In particular, taking $\ell_0 = 201$ shows the desired result. In fact, this same argument shows that there is one diagonal in $A$ that intersects at least $19700$ other diagonals.